# How do i encode my email newsletter to Base64 format?

Tags: html, encoding

As I see all these popular sites mostly encode their email newsletters to `base64` format so that Spam filters not really give any attention and those messages go smoothly.

Sample format:

Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

MIME-Version: 1.0

`Base64 Encoded Message Here. It's too long.`

Comment: you need to use a programming like Javascript for example. Then ask for a method to conver. ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript

Comment: What language are you developing with? There are plenty of libraries to employ b64 conversions depending on your runtime.